# HTML/CSS Navbar on top fixed, cant scroll the pade

Tags: html, css

So, my navbar is fixed on top of my site. Thats wanted. But now i cant scroll down the page anymore. 
I really dont know how to fix that. Removing the fixed tag isnt an option.

A div container on top of the code contains the class .bar. This is the one that controlls the top bar.

Theres my code guys.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20;
  font-family: proxima;
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
.img1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.leftbar {
  left: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 37px;
}
.rightbar {
  right: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 37px;
}
.bottombar {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <img src="img/invert.png" class="logo" alt="geht nicht">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="leftbar"></div>
  <div class="rightbar"></div>
  <div class="bottombar"></div>

  <nav class="">
    <ul class="">
      <a href="seite2.html">
        <li>Speakers</li>
      </a>
      <a href="seite3.html">
        <li>Headphones</li>
      </a>
      <a href="seite4.html">
        <li>All Products</li>
      </a>
      <a href="seite5.html">
        <li>The Journal</li>
      </a>
    </ul>

  </nav>
```

Comment: Removing or adding a fixed position wont stop your scroll from working

Comment: why you not use bootstrap?

Comment: @AbedPutra I think he's on the learning process. It's better to learn the hard code. Later, he can code using all frameworks without a problem. It's like plain JS and jQuery or other framework.

Comment: Why do you have left bar and right bar fixed if you want the nave to be fixed. I am not sure what you are trying to do with the page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Fixed or Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Is this more what you are looking for? - https://jsfiddle.net/c571rvxe/ I have removed `position:fixed` off everything and only applied it to the `nav`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `<div class="bar">`

```css
.bar{
    width:100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
}

.img1{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.leftbar {
    left:0;
    height: 1000px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:10px;
    margin-top:37px;
}
.rightbar {
    right:0;
    height: 1000px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:10px;
    margin-top:37px;
}
.bottombar {
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 10px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
<img src="img/invert.png" class="logo" alt="geht nicht">
    <div class="hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
<div class="leftbar"></div>
<div class="rightbar"></div>
<div class="bottombar"></div>

    <nav class="">
        <ul class="">
            <a href="seite2.html"><li>Speakers</li></a>
            <a href="seite3.html"><li>Headphones</li></a>
            <a href="seite4.html"><li>All Products</li></a>
            <a href="seite5.html"><li>The Journal</li></a>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    </div>
    
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae lacus arcu. Aliquam consectetur interdum hendrerit. Etiam in tristique justo, vel pulvinar dui. Aliquam ut eros odio. Aliquam laoreet non lorem ut semper. Aliquam posuere convallis orci maximus posuere. Sed vel leo at diam feugiat tincidunt. Praesent tincidunt magna ac malesuada elementum. Morbi cursus iaculis dolor, vel ornare turpis ullamcorper facilisis. Suspendisse velit dui, egestas at lorem gravida, lobortis consequat arcu. Sed at malesuada arcu, non finibus ex. Pellentesque augue libero, euismod at quam non, commodo egestas nulla.</p>
<p>
Maecenas congue ullamcorper turpis ut iaculis. Morbi quis lectus dignissim, molestie justo et, rutrum mi. Nam bibendum, sapien ac viverra bibendum, purus urna sodales turpis, eget semper orci nulla eget felis. Suspendisse et metus egestas, molestie risus eget, aliquet nisi. Aliquam augue arcu, maximus eget scelerisque in, rhoncus sodales lacus. Nam malesuada tempor felis, vitae pulvinar dolor sollicitudin id. Vestibulum gravida turpis interdum augue convallis, in rutrum risus luctus. Nunc luctus ultrices tempus. Donec nisl lacus, vestibulum id dolor nec, auctor ultrices eros. Pellentesque pharetra maximus pellentesque. Vivamus sed tincidunt ante. Nulla porttitor vehicula quam rhoncus accumsan. Nunc ultricies, lorem ut faucibus pretium, ante sem fermentum purus, ut pretium ex nulla vel augue. Quisque tempus lectus vel aliquet pharetra. In vel sem nec nisl luctus ultrices.
</p>
<p>


Nullam varius ac elit eget egestas. Duis quis lacus sed mauris pellentesque iaculis. Ut pretium nunc eget nisi suscipit, eu fringilla orci finibus. Maecenas vel convallis orci, a commodo nunc. Fusce egestas posuere urna, vitae fermentum ipsum maximus non. Pellentesque at luctus orci. Quisque condimentum mi a auctor ullamcorper. Sed sodales massa ac sodales tempus. Duis nisl est, elementum eu facilisis nec, egestas vel arcu.</p>

<p>


Morbi maximus condimentum accumsan. Donec at sem sagittis, elementum nisl eget, semper est. Nullam sollicitudin sodales aliquet. In sit amet nunc turpis. Etiam vehicula sem dui, id scelerisque sapien vulputate tristique. Pellentesque vitae lorem sit amet augue pretium hendrerit eu at tellus. Vestibulum ornare mauris at orci tincidunt, id blandit urna sollicitudin. Morbi porttitor, nisl quis tincidunt ornare, leo sapien malesuada mauris, in gravida nibh odio malesuada felis. In sit amet felis vulputate, luctus purus id, sollicitudin turpis. Nunc semper feugiat elit. Donec pretium orci vestibulum orci efficitur, sed dignissim nunc ultrices.</p>

<p>
Maecenas lacus mauris, luctus sed odio sed, dignissim consequat ex. Suspendisse elit ex, malesuada ac sagittis vel, sodales sit amet lacus. Aliquam ut rutrum mi. Proin vitae nibh cursus, fringilla tellus et, feugiat sem. Duis feugiat sapien id ipsum consequat blandit. In ac sollicitudin odio, at hendrerit augue. Quisque faucibus vitae metus vel pharetra. Sed et lorem nec ligula tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet libero eu felis rutrum elementum. Nam sem arcu, tincidunt id nibh et, faucibus fringilla lorem. Pellentesque interdum neque et urna vestibulum cursus. Etiam commodo laoreet lorem, non cursus elit sollicitudin vitae. Phasellus fringilla, est congue vestibulum ornare, quam tellus aliquam mi, at bibendum velit lacus nec felis.
    </p>
    
    <p>


Nullam varius ac elit eget egestas. Duis quis lacus sed mauris pellentesque iaculis. Ut pretium nunc eget nisi suscipit, eu fringilla orci finibus. Maecenas vel convallis orci, a commodo nunc. Fusce egestas posuere urna, vitae fermentum ipsum maximus non. Pellentesque at luctus orci. Quisque condimentum mi a auctor ullamcorper. Sed sodales massa ac sodales tempus. Duis nisl est, elementum eu facilisis nec, egestas vel arcu.</p>

<p>


Morbi maximus condimentum accumsan. Donec at sem sagittis, elementum nisl eget, semper est. Nullam sollicitudin sodales aliquet. In sit amet nunc turpis. Etiam vehicula sem dui, id scelerisque sapien vulputate tristique. Pellentesque vitae lorem sit amet augue pretium hendrerit eu at tellus. Vestibulum ornare mauris at orci tincidunt, id blandit urna sollicitudin. Morbi porttitor, nisl quis tincidunt ornare, leo sapien malesuada mauris, in gravida nibh odio malesuada felis. In sit amet felis vulputate, luctus purus id, sollicitudin turpis. Nunc semper feugiat elit. Donec pretium orci vestibulum orci efficitur, sed dignissim nunc ultrices.</p>

<p>
Maecenas lacus mauris, luctus sed odio sed, dignissim consequat ex. Suspendisse elit ex, malesuada ac sagittis vel, sodales sit amet lacus. Aliquam ut rutrum mi. Proin vitae nibh cursus, fringilla tellus et, feugiat sem. Duis feugiat sapien id ipsum consequat blandit. In ac sollicitudin odio, at hendrerit augue. Quisque faucibus vitae metus vel pharetra. Sed et lorem nec ligula tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet libero eu felis rutrum elementum. Nam sem arcu, tincidunt id nibh et, faucibus fringilla lorem. Pellentesque interdum neque et urna vestibulum cursus. Etiam commodo laoreet lorem, non cursus elit sollicitudin vitae. Phasellus fringilla, est congue vestibulum ornare, quam tellus aliquam mi, at bibendum velit lacus nec felis.
    </p>
```

Comment: Why? He couldn't scroll before, but now he can

Comment: Ok I removed my comment